# When requesting requests, I get the readable body of the page every other time, every other time, some hieroglyphs

Tags: python, utf-8, python-requests

When requesting requests, I get the readable body of the page every other time, every other time, some hieroglyphs

```py
import requests

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)

print(r)

print(r.text)
```

I get this answer Recoding doesn't help

```
200 
У|� �G7��ν�H�ãY�e[���zr�#�Ƈ��u������>��f��y'f:c��uZO���_�pI�ug���\B��!ؖ�e|�f�]���_�|��zp�����__l?l~����k��;>���;����7�~
�Q�y��[��zp���;0��)ty����Q0�]�
```

Comment: Looks like you're getting a binary file in response. The gibberish you're seeing is what you'd see for instance if you tried to display an image file as text. That doesn't mean that the request you made is incorrect, just that it doesn't make sense to try and display its response as text. You could check the [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header of the response in order to decide whether to display it as text or not

Comment: Thank you, approximately I understood the direction.